# Restrict pull request reviewers to admins

Tags: github

I'm trying to protect my main branch so only admins can push directly to it. Otherwise, they should create a pull request, ask for a review and **only admins** should be able to approve a review.

I marked those configurations:

[image]

It worked for disallowing non-members of org invited with write privileges from directly commiting to `main` branch:
[image]

It also worked for disallowing merging a pull request without approval:
[image]

However github still allow reviewers with **write access** to approve a pull request which makes absolutely no sense.

How do I limit reviewers so **only admins**, **not repo-invited users with write privilege** can approve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your screenshot shows that only admins can dismiss a PR not approve it.
You are probably looking for codeowner files and branch protection
https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches#restrict-who-can-push-to-matching-branches

Anything more complex than that and you are looking at CI/CD pipelines with OPA policy.